# PHP: Print contents of MySQL table, each row in it's own div

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in MySQL with 5 rows (filename, location, type, author, date) and I would like to use PHP to print something like the following:

```
<div id="file">
<a href="(location)">(filename)</a> - (author)<br>
(type) - (date)
</div>
```

I would like a new div to be created for every row in the table, is this possible?

Comment: sure its possible. what have you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo '<div id="file"><a href="'.$row['location'].'">'.$row['filename'].'</a> - a '.$row['author'].'<br>
    '.$row['type'].' - '.$row['date'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate like so:

```
<?php $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM files;') ?>
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) : ?>

    <div id="file">
        <a href="<?php echo $row['location'] ?>">
            <?php echo $row['filename'] ?>
        </a> 

        - <?php echo $row['author'] ?>

        <br>

        <?php echo $row['type'] ?> - <?php echo $row['date'] ?>
    </div>

<?php endwhile ?>
```